# Returning list values from two values recursively in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to create a list recursively by entering two values as a parameter, and that this returns the list.

I know that by doing the following:

```
function1 a b = [a..b]
```

Works correctly, but is not recursive.
Make it work recursively by entering a single parameter as follows:

```
function 0 = []
function a = function4 (a-1) ++ [a]
```

But I really have no idea how to do that it is created recursively with two parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check whether `a == b` instead of pattern matching:

```
function a b = if a == b then [b]
                         else a : function (succ a) b
```

Note that this can lead to problems if `a` is greater than `b` to begin with. Better check that too. And while we're at it, give you function a better name:

```
range :: (Ord a, Enum a) => a -> a -> [a]
range a b 
  | a > b     = []
  | a == b    = [b]
  | otherwise = a : range (succ a) b
```

Comment: I functioned correctly. Thank you!